# Ubuntu can't show GUI elements designed with .css files

Tags: java, css, ubuntu, javafx, netbeans

I'm working in a group on a Java project with the goal of designing a GUI with JavaFX.
The main structure of the GUI is complete and it works pretty well until the time we used CSS to customize some graphical details on buttons and text boxes and so on.
**The GUI runs without any problems on Windows and MAC, but when I try to run it on Ubuntu, a problem occurs.**

**As soon as I get the GUI up and running via Netbeans on Ubuntu, some details of the elements adjusted via .css files are no longer displayed.**
This problem occurs on several buttons and text boxes.

The Java project can be built and executed without error messages.
I only get a few warnings, but they do not cause any problems under Windows or MAC.

**During the build:**

```
Note: /.../.../.../.../nameOfClass.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint: unchecked for details.
Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.3
Launching <fx:jar> task from /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_161/jre/../lib/ant-javafx.jar
Warning: From JDK7u25 the Codebase manifest attribute should be used to restrict JAR repurposing.
         Please set manifest.custom.codebase property to override the current default non-secure value '*'.
Launching <fx:deploy> task from /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_161/jre/../lib/ant-javafx.jar
No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.
No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.
jfx-deployment-script:
jfx-deployment:
jar:
jfx-rebuild:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

**When running:**

```
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 9.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.161
```

Access to the .css files is set via paths in the Scenebuilder.
The Scenebuilder paste the path directly into the .fxml files.
Such as:

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="400.0" style="-fx-background-color: #EEEEEE;" stylesheets="@../styleSheets/loginStyle.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="packagename.login.LoginController">
```

The content of the .css file:

```
/*
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
*/

.button {
    -fx-background-color:  #007399;
    -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;
    -fx-stroke: #FFFFFF;
}

.button:hover{
    -fx-background-color: #328fad;
}

.button:pressed{
    -fx-background-color: #005c7a;
}
```

The funny thing is, as soon as I open the .fxml file in the scenebuilder,
everything is displayed correctly.
But as soon as I run the GUI by Netbeans on Ubuntu, the buttons looks different, or they are not shown.

---

**My Setup:**

Ubuntu 17.10

Netbeans 8.2 with Java: 1.8.0_161; 
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_161-b12;

JavaFX Scene Builder 9.0.1
Build Information
Version 9.0.1
Java Version: 9+181, Oracle Corporation

My local Java-Version by "java -version":
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)

---

**I have already tried the following solutions without success:**

I tried different local Java versions:
- java-8-openjdk-amd64
- java-9-openjdk-amd64
- jdk1.8.0_151
- jdk1.8.0_161
- jdk-9.0.4

I changed the Java Version for Netbeans under:
/netbeans-8.2/etc/netbeans.conf
I tried all these Java Versions above.
Netbeans runs only  with jdk 1.8* stable, but there were no solution for my problem.
I do not think the problem is because of the Java version.
My colleagues use the same Java, Netbeans and Scenebuilder versions on Windows and MAC and it works for them.

I have changed my desktop environment from gnome to xfce, kubuntu and unity.
But the problem continues.

I cloned the project via git on an other Laptop with the same Ubuntu, Netbeans and Scenebuilder Versions and the Problem also occurs here.

Unfortunately I can not find any logfiles for javafx or anything like that.

If someone had an idea to fix this bug, I would be very happy.

Best regards

Comment: Are you rebuilding the jar file specifically for your Linux machine? It's not clear if the build logs are from the linux machine, or just general. If you are rebuilding it on the linux machine, try just testing the jar file that works correctly on the other machines and see if the problem arises when you run that on your linux box. Also check the jar file you create (the one that isn't working), and see if the CSS file is included and is in the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a solution. I used a "Rectangle" Object, created with Scenebuilder. The Option for "Smooth" was unchecked. This caused the bugs under Linux machines.

> Property description for isSmooth():
>   Defines whether antialiasing hints are used or not for this Shape. If the value equals true the rendering hints are applied.

To fix this issue, set Smooth to "true" under
 "Properties: Rectangle > Specific > Smooth